# Is Etrecheck safe to use and is this safe place to download?

Tags: applications, data-transfer

I wanted to check my system and heard about EtreCheck.

1) Is it safe app to use?

2) Is this safe place to download it from?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's a safe app, but the website of the maker (that website you have there, etrecheck.com) is indeed where you should download it from if you do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Etrecheck is safe to use.

And yes, you should definitely download it from the official website.

Countless people (myself included) have used Etrecheck as a troubleshooting tool. In fact, if you browse [Apple's support communities](https://discussions.apple.com/welcome) you'll see it often used there as a troubleshooting tool.